# Debugging GWT in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin

Got an issue here.  I've written a GWT script to alternate between two images which requires the 2 names in the URL.  This works fine when I compile and run on my PC, but when I try and run in debug mode in eclipse, I can't parse the name.

I.e.

http://intra.net/flick.html?pics=foo.png,bar.png

Works fine, whereas when I add to that to the URL eclipse gives me

http://127.0.0.1:8888/flickbook.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&pics=foo.png,bar.png

It complains that pics is not defined.

Where do I add the arguments to the debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with Google Chrome, wasn't in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is imho malformed.

You have a colon (a `:`) between blockedcontent and 9997.

Comment: that is what Eclipse gives me.

Comment: Sorry, don't get it, how can eclpise "give you an url"??

Comment: Have you used GWT debug with eclipse?

Comment: Yes I have ... but I simply don't understand your problem, why don't you type the correct url in the browser?

Comment: I have!  When I click debug in eclipse I get a URL to open in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Why is eclipse generating the hosting page as flickbook instead of flick?

Can you try with

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/flick.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&pics=foo.png,bar.png
```